# Has Joker ever mentioned...Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, dc, the-joker, crossovers, easter-egg

Yes, you've read it right. *Star Wars*. Why would I ask such ridiculous question? Well, the answer lies in the voice behind Joker in the animated series and most of Batman games, who is no other than Mark Hamill, known from his little role as a [boy who didn't want to work as a moisture farmer any more](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker), and actors are well known to introduce such Easter eggs about their other movies.

Comment: @JakeGould Yes, and whoever else. But to be honest I don't recall that anyone at any stage was advertising animated Batman as "movie with an actor that played Luke Skywalker" and personally I didn't even know for a long time that it was THE Mark Hamil behind the killer clown. Anyway, the question was about any easter eggs, no matter who placed them.

Comment: Also in recent "The Flash" TV series he played Joker's ripoff, The Trickster, and in one of the episodes he had a nice Darth Vader moment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWxZ6hmWbFA

Comment: Note that Hamill also played the Trickster (twice) in the "Flash" TV show from 1990-91. Might be interesting to have him encounter John Wesley Shipp's Earth-2 Flash (as Shipp was Barry Allen/The Flash in that 1990 show). And it's likely that his 1990 turn as the Trickster predates his voice-over role as the Joker, as BTAS debuted in 1992.

Comment: Not sure what any of this has to do with Hamill's role in *Corvette Summer*....

Comment: [Harley Quinn as Han Solo](https://comicnewbies.com/2015/01/13/harley-quinn-as-han-solo/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Yes.**

"[**May the Floss be with you**](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Love)"

and

[image]

Comment: There was also an episode of Batman: The Animated Series ("Birds of a Feather") where Veronica Vreeland says, "*I got a bad feeling about this.*"

Comment: +1 for may the floss with you but how is "Return of Joker" is related? Its a common phrase.. doesn't look like picked from Return of the Jedi

Comment: @HBhatia - I'm honestly not sure how much more blatant they could make it, short of writing in the word "Jedi" and crossing it out with the word "Joker"

Comment: Accepted for the "floss be with you". "Return of..." is bit too common.

Comment: As an aside, the 1991 SNES game "Return of the Joker" was re-released as "Revenge of the Joker". This would seem to be a clear reference to Return of the Jedi's original title "Revenge of the Jedi", albeit pre-dating Hamill's involvement by two years.

Comment: @Richard Also worth mentioning that the logo behind the words looks an awful lot like the logo for the Rebel Alliance, twisted slightly to one side.

Comment: @MattThrower Pretty sure that's supposed to imply the shape of the batarang that Terry uses through the series.

Comment: @Mark I'm sure you're right. But that doesn't mean that the shape of the batarang wasn't inspired by the Rebel logo :)

Comment: @Valorum "I'm honestly not sure how much more blatant they could make it" - can you perhaps elaborate? The name "Return of the ___" is fairly commonplace; is it just because "Joker" begins with a J, or is there anything more to it?