# Does the phrase "Return of the XXX" actually predate Return of the Jedi and Return of the King in common usage?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, history-of, return-of-the-jedi, title-explanation

The comments on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111466/3823) involve a disagreement about whether *Return of the Joker* is a direct reference to *Return of the Jedi*, with one party arguing is it obviously a reference and the other stating that it's just a common phrase.

There's another obvious eariler example in LOTR *Return of the King*.

**Does the phrase *Return of the XXXX* actually predate *Return of the King* to any significant degree, particular in the titles of works of fiction?**

Comment: Even earlier *The Return of She* by H.Rider Haggard.

Comment: Bonus question, if it fits into anyone's answer to this question:   Was *Return of the Jedi* directly inspired by *Return of the King* ?

Comment: @ThePopMachine "*Was 'Return of the Jedi' directly inspired by 'Return of the King' ?*" - the original title was going to be "Revenge of the Jedi", but [Lucas later changed "Revenge" to "Return"](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Lucas-change-the-original-title-of-Return-of-the-Jedi-to-its-current-name)

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&O_1=notexact&TERM_1=COVERART&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=notexact&TERM_2=INTERIORART&USE_3=title_language_free&O_3=exact&TERM_3=English&USE_4=title_title&O_4=contains&TERM_4=Return+of+the+&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: One could make the argument that none of these examples (including The Return of the King) are any good, since they begin with "the".

Comment: Except Return of Brute, on second thought. Even so... I did not understand why "Return of the Joker" is supposed to obviously attempt to invoke Return of the Jedi...

Comment: Here the return of the answer by user14111, but for movies: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=The+return+of+the+&release_date=,1982-12-31&sort=year,asc
The title format "The return of ..." is so commonplace that parodies of it are  commonplace.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting side note: many of the titles being included in the answers use "[The] Return of [Blank]" as a simple way of titling a sequel - referring to a character from an earlier work returning. "Return of the Jedi" and "The Return of the King" however refer to major plot points - entities which have been gone long before the beginning of the work in question.

So, there are really two different concepts that could be parodied/emulated here.

Comment: And _The Return of the King_ was not Tolkien's favoured title, but rather _The War of the Ring_, precisely because it was a spoiler.

Comment: The title sounds so wrong...

Answer (score 51):

Conceptually the phrase would have been familiar English usage from at least the 13th century, the first usage of note I was able to find was a reference to the biblical story made by Rembrant's painting titled ["Return of the Prodigal Son"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_Prodigal_Son_(Rembrandt)) (1661 - 1669):

[image]

<sup>Hermitage museum Saint Petersburg</sup>

Comment: The painting's title is in Dutch, this is a translation. I don't know how soon it was translated into English.

Comment: @user132647 That's a good point, I might do some more digging to get a bit of a clearer answer.

Comment: The parable is older than the idiom.  The scene has been painted many times before and after Rembrandt.  Rembrandt's fame has helped spread the idiom across European languages during the next 100 years. An example painting named in the English language already using the idiom as of 1772: http://www.steigrad.com/west-the-return-of-the-prodigal-son

Comment: It’s not really a translation, as the original Dutch version doesn’t have the word prodigal or the equivalent, but uses ‘lost’

Comment: The return of the prodigal son is a parable from the Christian Bible, as you say, it far predates Remembrant.

Comment: @JirkaHanika The parable is generally referred to only as "the prodigal son", though.

Comment: @KyleStrand - By "idiom" I was specifically referring to "the return of the".  That refers to a specific scene from the parable.  Prior to Rembrandt, the scene was depicted many times, but described differently.  Since Rembrandt, we are seeing the returns of variously labelled sons all across European languages, and eventually even other significant returns.

Comment: I'm sure that 1772 isn't the earliest usage in English, everyone is welcome to improve on that.

Answer (score 36):

Return of the [Something] is a relatively common - and old - title. If you consider the variant "The Return of the [Something]", it becomes even more widespread.

Earliest example I could find was "The Return of the Native", by Thomas Hardy - 1878. It is by no means unique.

[image]

While "Return of the Jedi" is a fairly famous title, alongside "Return of the King", those titles are so common that is difficult to say later title was influenced by this or that previous work.

Comment: Actually the Tolkien title is ***The** Return of the King*, isn't it?

Comment: Agreed. "[The] Return of / to ..." is such an obvious title for a sequel that it was a trope *long* ago. Surely, no modern author would use it unless they're intentionally invoking that trope for a nostalgic "retro" effect.

Comment: Standard disclaimer here that Tolkien didn't actually want the title _The Return of the King_, but rather _The War of the Ring_ (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_King#Title_and_publication)

Answer (score 29):

### Yes.

The novel [Return of the Brute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Brute), by [Liam O'Flaherty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liam_O%27Flaherty), was published in 1929.

[image]

And here are some movies from the '30s.

[The Return of Doctor X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_Doctor_X)
is from 1939.

[image]

[The Return of the Scarlet Pimpernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_the_Scarlet_Pimpernel)
is from 1937.

[image]

[The Return of Chandu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_Chandu)
is from 1934.

[image]

[Return of the Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Terror) is also from 1934.

[image]

Comment: A slightly more modern variant (which still predates Star Wars) is "Return to the Planet of the Apes".

Comment: "Son of Sequel Strikes Again!" (Oh! My!)

Answer (score 18):

While this is not the earliest, as far as popularity in its own time, this one could be right up there with other much more recent "returns":

[The Return of Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_Sherlock_Holmes), published in 1905.

[image]

Comment: +1. I wanted to add this example. "The Return of XXX" is a classic title for many serialized works.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

[The Return Of Frank James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_of_Frank_James) (1940) came long before *Return of the Jedi* (1983) and *Return of the King* (1955).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

"The return of XXX" is a classic title for many serialized works. For example, [The Return of Sherlock Holmes](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Return_of_Sherlock_Holmes) was published in 1905 (as mentioned in Lee Mosher's answer).

We can draw a parallel between the returns of Sherlock Holmes and the Joker. Sherlock Holmes was assumed to have died in *The Final Problem* (published in 1893) and got revived in *the Return of Sherlock Homes*. *the Return of the Joker* is part of *Batman Beyond*, a futuristic timeline (set in 2019!) where the Joker was assumed to be dead.

There is also a [return of Tarzan](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Return_of_Tarzan) published in 1913, so this kind of title was probably common for everything related to the adventure genre.

A short [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20return%20of%22%20comics) returns many "the return of XXX" titles related to comics characters:

1. the return of Superman
2. the return of Bruce Wayne
3. the return of Tarzan (published in 1973). I don't know how it relates to the novel mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Shakespeare’s *Measure for Measure*, written 1603–1604,  has the line, “The contents of this is the return of the Duke.”  The King James Bible of 1611 translates 1 Kings 20:22 as, “for at the return of the year the king of Syria will come up against thee.”

These are not titles, but they predate Rembrandt’s “De terugkeer van de verloren zoon” and the Shakespeare line is not translated from another language.

*Return* as a verb appears earlier than *return* as a noun, but something like this usage probably appeared by the late 1300s.

Comment: Possibly worth posting a Google N-gram of this, as it shows an interesting pattern of reducing usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+return+of%2Creturn+of+the%2Creturn+of+a%2Cthe+return+of+the%2Ca+return+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20return%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creturn%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creturn%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20return%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20return%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

"Return of the Werewolf" was published in 1976.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6661032-return-of-the-werewolf

Looking at the Google N-Gram Viewer, we can see that the phrase enters usage even before Google can start tracking it in the 1500's. I tried putting in 1200 for the year start, but 1500 is as far back as Google goes.

[image: Google N-Gram Viewer]

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+return+of+the&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3